# How to make a request to the same container where the request came out

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

I have this setting in `docker-compose.yml` causing it to bring up a container with port 8080 exposed.

[image]

Inside that container, I have some applications located inside the `src` directory, separated as `sub-modules`.

[image]

I'm using LARAVEL FRAMEWORK, I made the following configuration to get the API URL. Inside that `wrapper_app` config, there is the URL `php:8080/app` which is also an application.

[image]

The request is going from "ACADEMY-SAAS" to "APP", but without success.

[image]

[image]

**How to make a folder inside the `container` communicate with another folder inside the same `container` via HTTP?**

I also tried to put in the `docker-compose.yml`, inside the `php` service, the link with itself, but when I upload the container, the error of "recursiveness" is displayed.

Comment: Since it's not a cross-container request, can you try replacing php with localhost? And, since your docker compose file is mapping port 8080 on the host to port 80 on the container, can you try changing the port to 80 too? So you would have `localhost:80/app/public` as your wrapper_app setting.

Comment: Worked perfectly! thank you my friend!
Great :check

Comment: How do the image files you attached relate to your application and the Compose setup?  Compose can't directly run a PNG file, file example.  Can you edit the question and replace the images with your actual source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to check, have you tried localhost:8080 or just localhost? Since it is just communicating with itself, I think it may not need the container name

Comment: That's right.
as I answered right above in the comment of our contributor friend, being in the same container I don't need to pass the name of the container, I'm already inside it and I refer only using localhost.

Excellent vision, I lost a lot of time not to see high so obviously.